# No ripple effect in compound view

Tags: android, view, ripple

I have compound view, root tag is merge, in code of this view i set background according attribute app:hasbackground which i defined in attrs. Here is the method:

```
private fun updateBackground(data: ViewData) {
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,
            if (data.hasBackground){
                R.drawable.bg_view
            }else {
                R.drawable.bg_ripple
            }
        )
    }
```

the problem i have is that if i set onClick for this view in fragment/activity it doesnt have any ripple effect but it triggers action that i setted.
Here is R.drawable.bg_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:radius="0dp"
    android:color="@color/surface_200">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/surface_100" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_12dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

if i add android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" in view with merge tag it doesn't working, if i add this in place where i use custom view it starts working but ripple doesn't have corners